# DB ParameterGroup not found, not allowed to do cross region copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am using the AWS command line tool and am having issue with copying the parameter group to a different region

Error:

```
An error occurred (DBParameterGroupNotFound) when calling the CopyDBParameterGroup operation: DB ParameterGroup not found, not allowed to do cross region copy.
```

The command is:

```
 >aws rds copy-db-parameter-group  --source-db-parameter-group-identifier arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:MyActID:pg:source-para-group --target-db-parameter-group-identifier  dest-para-group  --target-db-parameter-group-description  dest-para-group-description
```

I also tried with:

```
 >aws rds copy-db-parameter-group  --source-db-parameter-group-identifier arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:MyActID:pg:source-para-group --target-db-parameter-group-identifier  arn:aws:rds:ap-south-1:MyActID:pg:dest-para-group  --target-db-parameter-group-description  arn:aws:rds:ap-south-1:MyActID:pg:dest-para-group-description
```

Please let help me if anyone else come across the similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [copy-db-parameter-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/copy-db-parameter-group.html),  the tricky part :

- If the **source** DB parameter group is in a **different region than the copy**, specify a valid DB parameter group ARN, for example arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789012:pg:special-parameters .

Apparently it is a "from - to" copy option. Try using the TARGET region AWS credential when making the copy, then specify the source ARN.

Comment: Thanks for your kind replay. Yes I have followed the same. I am pretty sure ARN I have used is correct and also I used target AWS credentials.